# Need urgently assistance in LaTeX - unable to change the document class without totally blowing my thesis

Tags: memoir, document-classes, report

First of all I'm a beginner in LaTeX, of course I used it for writing short articles but never for a thesis...
For This reason (now I think it was stupid) I looked for a sample of a thesis and I was working with that thesis for several weeks;

Now I discovered that with a bachelor thesis of 30 pages the document class "memoir" is probably the wrong choice and tried to change it into report;
But if I do that I get only error messages and for me it's impossible to solve it without losing all the format and design;

Now the main problem is that 'memoir' it's used for double sided sheets, that's why the margins are changing from page to page; If I print only one side then the left margin should be wieder than the right one and it shouldn't rotate;
Also that there is a page free between each chapter is not what I want;

Now what do you suggest to me: To change it to report or to try to modify the memoir in the right way?
Please I would be very happy if someone could help me because I feel kind of lost right now...

Here is the sample LaTeX code:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}    
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib]{memoir} 
\usepackage{datetime}

% Declare figure/table as a subfloat.
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
% Better page layout for A4 paper, see memoir manual.
\settrimmedsize{297mm}{210mm}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt} 
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth} 
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth} 
\settypeblocksize{634pt}{448.13pt}{*} 
\setulmargins{4cm}{*}{*} 
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1.5} 
\setmarginnotes{17pt}{51pt}{\onelineskip} 
\setheadfoot{\onelineskip}{2\onelineskip} 
\setheaderspaces{*}{2\onelineskip}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout
%
\frenchspacing
% Font with math support: New Century Schoolbook
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\OnehalfSpacing 
%
% Sets numbering division level
\setsecnumdepth{subsection} 
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
%
% Chapter style (taken and slightly modified from Lars Madsen Memoir Chapter 
% Styles document
\usepackage{calc,soul,fourier} 
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{gray}{\color{white}\thechapter}% 
        }}%
        \rotatebox{90}{% 
                \resizebox{%
                \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
        \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
    \makebox[0pt][c]{% aka \rlap
        \makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
    }}
\makechapterstyle{daleifmodif}{
    \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
    \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\scshape} 
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{} \renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
    \renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
    \renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
    \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\color{gray}\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleifmodif}

\makepagestyle{myvf} 
\makeoddfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeevenfoot{myvf}{}{\thepage}{} 
\makeheadrule{myvf}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness} 
\makeevenhead{myvf}{\small\textsc{\leftmark}}{}{} 
\makeoddhead{myvf}{}{}{\small\textsc{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{myvf}


\makeindex


\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amsfonts}                
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}                            
\usepackage{amssymb}                
\usepackage{amsthm}                     
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                   
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}



% Für Pseudocode Kapitel 3

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
 \renewcommand\lstlistingname{Teil}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{16cm}{#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}



\usepackage{hyperref}                           
\usepackage{microtype}


 %reduziert falsche Formatierungen              
\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000





\DeclareMathOperator \ggT {ggT}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb N}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb Z}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb Q}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb R}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb C}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb F}
\newcommand{\PP}{\mathbb P}
%

%An initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
    \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.33,nindent=0em]{
        \color{gray}
            {\textsc{#1}}}{}}


\renewenvironment{proof}{{\bfseries Beweis: }}{$\hfill \Box$}
% Anpassung der Proof Umgebung

%Anpassung von plain, definition und erstellung von theoremstyle kommentar
\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\nopagebreak\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\nopagebreak\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {} 

\newtheoremstyle{definition}
  {0.5\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {0.5\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\nopagebreak\normalfont}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\nopagebreak\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {} 


\newtheoremstyle{kommentar}
  {}   
  {}   
  {}  
  {}       
  {\bfseries} 
  {:}         
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} 
  {}          


\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}[lem]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{satz}[lem]{Satz}
\newtheorem{kor}[lem]{Korollar}



\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[lem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{beispiel}[lem]{Beispiel}
\newtheorem{algo}[lem]{Algorithmus}

\theoremstyle{kommentar}
\newtheorem*{bemerkung}{Bemerkung}

\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{Sample 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Subsample 1}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Subsample 2}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Sample 2}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Sample 3}
\lipsum
\lipsum[1-5]
\appendix
\chapter{Sample appendix}
\lipsum
\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

I would be so so happy about any suggestions what I could do...!! Thank you very very very much in advance... :)

Comment: Did you look at the `oneside` option in [`memman.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf)?

Comment: report and memoir act the same way here, you sound like you need `oneside`

Comment: Like I said, I'm a beginner... Can you explain it to me or should I google it? Because I never heard of it..

Comment: just add it where you have the other options `a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib`

Comment: You don't _have_ to google, most classes have an option of that name so it should be mentioned in any tutorial and it will also be in the manual for the memoir class that you are using

Comment: Okay, that was easy... May I ask one last thing; Do I have any disadvantages staying with memoir instead or report or is it totally unimportant?

Comment: If anything, you will have advantages using `memoir`.

Comment: Welcome! @Johannes_B Doesn't that rather depend on institutional requirements? I would say check the formatting rules first or, failing that, now. Memoir will do something nicely by default, but your institution may not like theses which are typeset nicely and then it can be more difficult to override the defaults than to start with one of the standard classes. (But you're the thesis expert here.)

Comment: I recommend not loading the packages you don't need. At least some of those packages are unnecessary and loading packages you don't need means trouble. (**color** is definitely not needed, although it shouldn't cause trouble.) Don't load packages twice. Don't load both **fouriernc** and **fourier**.

Comment: @cfr You are right, as `memoir` and `KOMA` provide so many preset options, it is harder to tweak the default to strange institutional requirements.

Comment: `babel` will override `datetime` in your example. Do you need to display dates/times?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

You need some additional `memoir` options:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib,oneside,openany]{memoir}
```

The `oneside` option will keep the layout of each page the same. The `openany` option will let chapters start on the next page with no intervening empty page.

Comment: `openany` is meaningless with `oneside`. From the documentation: "If the `oneside` option is used [chapters] start on the next new page, but if the `twoside` option is used the starting page may differ, as follows.
`openright` [Description of the behavior] `openleft` [Desc.] `openany` [Desc.]"

Comment: @Paul Gessler: You are correct but if the OP ever changes to `twoside` then `openany` will be what he needs to avoid a blank page before a `chapter`.